# Laravel mix import node module in project

Tags: laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

I'm trying to import a node module in a custom module i'm creating in public folder.

What i'm doing in webpack.mix.js

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .vue()
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .js('node_modules/normalize-wheel', 'public/assets')
    .version();
```

In script file

```
import NormalizeWheel from '../normalize-wheel.js'
```

the error i'm getting

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '../normalize-wheel.js' does not provide an export named 'default'
```

How can i import from node_modules folder correctly with laravel mix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone who has the same question/issue as me, i found an easy solution.

In your app.js file just do

```
window.NormalizeWheel = require('normalize-wheel');
```

Webpack via Laravel Mix bundles in up in one file /public/js/app.js which can be attached anywhere.